# How to solve django custom user Login error: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a django custom user login form, When user login the below error shows 
    please help

```
            Forbidden (403)
    CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

    Help
    Reason given for failure:

        CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

The below Error shows in terminal

```
    UserWarning: A {% csrf_token %} was used in a t
emplate, but the context did not provide the value.  This is usually caused by not using RequestContext.
  "A {% csrf_token %} was used in a template, but the context "
[08/May/2018 23:44:13] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7798
```

here is my view

```js
  @csrf_protect
def user_login(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('username')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return render_to_response('app/index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("You're account is disabled.")
        else:
            return render_to_response('app/login.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('app/login.html', {}, context)
```

here is my login html code

```html
  <form class="form-horizontal" name="LoginForm" action="/login/" method="post">
                 {% csrf_token %}
                 {% if next %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                 {% endif %}
```

How to do it? When user successfully login the User_Profile template show , buth the URL remain http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ I want to change the url to http://127.0.0.1:8000/students_profile

here is URL

```js
    url(r'^students_profile/', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='students_profile'),
```

Here is login form

```html
 <form class="form-horizontal" name="LoginForm" action="." method="post">
                 {% csrf_token %}
                 {% if next %}
                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
                 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template is already protected by `{% csrf_token %}` no need to have the decorator in your view:
Also, rather than using render_to_response, you can use `render` from `django.shortcuts`

I reduce your codes a little bit, it's better to use

```
from django.contrib import messages

def user_login(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return render(request,'app/index.html',{})
            # the else statement
            return HttpResponse("You're account is disabled.")
        # the else statement
        messages.add_message(request,messages.WARNING,'Credentials invalid')
    return render(request,'app/login.html', {})
```

in templates retrieve the message like this:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
   {% for message in messages %}
   <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
 </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thanks now there is no error , but I am not able to login , in terminal this error shows ,  ( Credentials invalids
[09/May/2018 00:51:20] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7921
)

Comment: because of this line in my code `print('Credentials invalids')` that's because username or password is invalid

Comment: I can login to default admin  with same user name and password , but in custom login form I can not

Comment: you got a typo in your the code, `password = request.POST.get('password')`, not `request.POST.get('username')`

Comment: Thank you so much now everything is work fine, Please one more thing how to show error message if user name or password is invalid?

Comment: you can use django message framework. i'm gonna
 update my answer

Comment: check out my answer

Comment: what is the template name ,where i have to put this code {% if messages %}

Comment: YOu can retrieve the message in your template, login.html

Comment: Thank you so much dear sir , I got it now everything is working fine

Comment: glad to be of help!

Comment: I have another problem also in this project, can I take help from you?

Comment: let us continue in chat, I don't see the option to jump to chat

Comment: I am not able to come chat,

Comment: please let me know How to send my code for validating

Comment: i have course model , I need to enroll custom user as student in course table  and after user login show related course to students

Comment: Hi , I posted this issue here,..   please check it . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242278/how-to-enroll-custom-user-as-students-in-django

Comment: dear sir one more thing is left here please, when user login successfully, the URL always  remain (http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/) I want to change this url when user is in student_profile for login to (studenthome)

Comment: use `redirect('url_name')` or `HttpResponseRedirect('raw_url')` after login, to redirect the user to the view that you want

Comment: where I have to put this code in Form Action URL or anywhere else ?

Comment: after user logged in `login(request, user)` and then `return redirect('your_url_name')`

Comment: after user login the student profile template show fine, but the Url is remain http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/, I want  when user is in homepage the url should show http://127.0.0.1:8000/studenprofle/.  how to redirect?

Comment: add your URL patterns to your question, I wonder where I can move to discussion, this is such a long discussion here

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please check your views.py I haven't seen your code but i guess you may have rendered without RequestContext that's why above error is showing. So you better use

```
render(request, 'template_name', {params});
```

From docs
render() is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

Comment: hi, I used this line, is it fine ?  return render_to_response('app/index.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: what I should use {params})' ?

Comment: Well the code you wrote is fine but render_to_response is deprecated since version 2.0 so you better use render() and please check your settings.py to be sure where you have address your template folder structure also to be sure 'app/index.html' is right path

Comment: and {params} is used to pass the variable to template. For example: return render(request, 'app/index.html', { 'title': 'title_name' })