# How to enroll custom user as students in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have django course model and custom user as students 
I added some course for logged student, Now i need to show the profile of user or  student and his course in student_profile.html

here is my model for course

```js
class Course(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField('Profile', blank=True)
    Course_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Duration_Time = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Course_Fee = models.IntegerField()
    Discount_Fee = models.IntegerField()
    Course_Image = models.FileField()
    Course_Description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Course_Name + ' - ' + self.Duration_Time
```

here is model profile

```js
class Profile(models.Model):
    STUDENT = 1
    TEACHER = 2
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (STUDENT, 'Student'),
        (TEACHER, 'Teacher'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, help_text='Required.')
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    # this method called for admin panel
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'profile'
        verbose_name_plural = 'profiles'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

here is my students profile template

```js
                       {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                         <p>welcome {{ user.first_name }} --
                         {% for course in user.profile.course_set.all %}
                              {{ course.name }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
                         {% empty %}
                              <span>No course</span>
                         {% endfor %}
                         </p>
                       {% endif %}

                      <p><a href="/logout">Logout</a></p>
```

When student login in profile template  showing only studentname
Here is result in browser

```js
welcome studnet for course -- ,

Logout
```

Comment: add the other models. Profile

Comment: Sir I added model profile code also

Comment: updated it in my answer, instead of `{{ course.name }}` add `{{ course.Course_Name }}`. in template

Comment: Thank you very much dear Sir you really  help me a lot , now everything showing fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `ManyToManyField` in your Course Model, named:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    #  other fields 
    students = models.ManyToManyField('Profile',blank=True)`
```

So when you have a profile instance, this query `profile_instance.course_set.all()` will display all the courses that this *profile/student* has attended

In your view, don't override `get_queryset()`

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>welcome {{ user.first_name }} -- 
    {% for course in user.profile.course_set.all %}
         {{ course.Course_Name }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% empty %}
         <span>No course</span>
    {% endfor %}
    </p> 
{% endif %}

<p><a href="/logout">Logout</a></p>
...
```

Comment: the Django admin panel? just go to Course, you will  see a box where you can choose  profiles

Comment: there is profile option which is including these field (Phone number, Email confirmed, Role) there is no any chose file to enroll user in course

Comment: Go to Course model, choose a course instance, inside it, you will see how you can add multiple profiles

Comment: dear sir i found that now I can add course to student , Please give a complete example from profile html to display student and his course

Comment: i need for a method in my view and a logic code for display in template student_profile.html

Comment: I added the template code , showing nothing , please write the view code for this

Comment: is the view for Course Model?

Comment: there is one view for display course list , now I need  for another view to display students and his course in profile template, please check the course view in above my code

Comment: class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'app/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'object_list'  
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Course.objects.all()

Comment: Sir I dded your new code, showing this line  welcome studnetName  for course -- not showing the course name which student enrolled

Comment: because there's no course for the current logged in user... try adding courses for the user in Admin

Comment: in student profile template showing only this line (  welcome studnetName for course --

Logout  )

Comment: I added two course for this student but showing same thing

Comment: to avoid long discussion, update your question with your current code